# Unwanted red border in Google Chrome 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit) around <table> code

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Some days before I noticed red border on any site on the web in different places. I suppose it appears around `<table>` content. For example look at attached screenshot of this site's bottom.

How can I get rid of red borders?

My machine: iMac 27-inch, Late 2013, OS X El Capitan 10.11.1.
My browser: in question's title

[image: screenshot28-oct-2015-13-46]

Comment: can you check which add-ons are enabled in chrome? My guess is the "web-developer" addon which lets you add a border to many html elements

Comment: My sorry. Yes, benjaminS, you're right. I turned off the extension "Show Tables 0.1" (useful dev tool to show hidden tables) and borders are gone. Feel a little bit stupid. This solved my problem.

Comment: I'll add it as a solution then! thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1):

Those **red borders** are often used by web developers. There are some **Add-Ons** (in Chrome as well as in Firefox) which provide them.

To disable them, go into your browser add-ons and **uninstall/disable them**. Some addons(like the well known "Web-Developer" Addon) let you enable/disable the border on the fly. Check the "contour" or "border" settings and disable the respective option.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off hardware acceleration in Chrome. **Settings** > **Advanced** > **Use hardware acceleration when available** or just type **chrome://settings/system** to get required screen. Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGGPZ.png)